# Polymer sending/receiving events among sibling elements

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Assume I have two sibling elements, and `<element-b>` fires an event. How does `<element-a>` listen to the event without having to add imperative code to the parent?

```
<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <element-a></element-a>
  <element-b></element-b>
</dom-module>
```

where `<element-a>` and `<element-b>` are:

```
<dom-module id="element-a">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
    </style>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'element-a',
      listeners: {
        'element-b': 'handleEvent',
      },
      ready: function() {
        console.log('fired from element a')
        this.fire('element-a', {employee: ''});
      },
      handleEvent: function (e) {
        console.log('received element b event', e)
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="element-b">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
    </style>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'element-b',
      listeners: {
        'element-a': 'handleEvent',
      },
      ready: function() {
        console.log('fired from element b')
        this.fire('element-b', {employee: ''});

      },
      handleEvent: function (e) {
        console.log('received element a event', e)
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`<iron-signals>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-signals) for that.

Add an `<iron-signals>` listener in one element:

```
// element-b
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-element-a="_onSignalElementA"></iron-signals>

_onSignalElementA: function(e) {
  const newDate = e.detail;
  ...
}
```

...and fire an `iron-signal` event (with data) in the other:

```
// element-a
this.fire('iron-signal', {name: 'element-a', data: new Date()});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
  Polymer({
    is: 'element-a',
    _onClick: function() {
      this.fire('iron-signal', {name: 'element-a', data: new Date()});
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'element-b',
    _onSignalElementA: function(e) {
      this._message = `b received: ${e.detail}`;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-signals/iron-signals.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <element-a></element-a>
      <element-b></element-b>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="element-a">
    <template>
      <button on-tap="_onClick">Fire event</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <dom-module id="element-b">
    <template>
      <iron-signals on-iron-signal-element-a="_onSignalElementA"></iron-signals>
      <div>[[_message]]</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PWRvgK?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using that but do you know why it advises to avoid using it `Note: avoid using iron-signals whenever you can use a controller (parent element) to mediate communication instead.`

Comment: I think it's a design decision. On one hand, the mediator pattern limits the data scope at the cost of extra plumbing (and potentially verbose code). On the other hand, using `<iron-signals>` can reduce code size at the cost of maintainability. In a more complex example, where `element-a` and `element-b` are distant cousins instead of immediate siblings, `<iron-signals>` would still work, but it may be harder to reason about your code.

Comment: So the alternative would be to make the parent a mediator which results in verbose code. Is there anyway to make the code cleaner and encapsulate the behavior of the mediator instead of adding code directly into the parent?